# robot.txt syntax not understood

Tags: regex, robots.txt

I am getting this error on the first line of robot.txt `User-agent: *`

my robot.txt is as follows:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /Search/
Disallow: /_layouts/ 
Disallow: /blog/_layouts/
Disallow: /Blog/_layouts/
Disallow: /ReusableContent/
Disallow: /Reports%20List/
Disallow: /WorkflowTasks/
Disallow: /SiteCollectionImages/
Disallow: /Documents/Forms/
Disallow: /Pages/Forms/
Disallow: /Internet/
```

I have figured there is a space `/Reports%20List/`. is this creating issues?
I am not very much sure. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "getting this error" - from where? Should it be `User-Agent` with a capital `A`?

Comment: SEO people in my company are getting this error. and I have looked around. `A` need not to be capital.

Comment: So you can't reproduce this error yourself? You should ask them for whatever you need to reproduce it.

Comment: Have you tried `Reports List` ?

Comment: Is it possible that the file is not a plain text file? If it's a MS Word document or HTML, the robots.txt parser won't understand it. Easy way to determine if the `%20` is causing a problem: remove it and see if the file works then.

Answer (score 0):

The trouble here is with the 3 invisible bytes at the beginning of the UTF-8 formatted robots.txt file, the so called BOM (byte order mask). This BOM is optional. Yes, you need the file UTF-8 formatted, but Google currently does not like the optional BOM in the expected clear and simple robots.txt file and parsing fails.

You can read a more detailed explanation [HERE](http://www.milevis.com/Tips/Details/42).